# Gradle task to do processing when external process is "ready"

Tags: gradle

I would like my gradle task to:

1. Execute a command (external process to "start my server").
2. Wait for a certain output from my external process say "Server Is Ready" in the stdout.
3. Do something in my gradle task (basically to talk to my external task).
4. When I am done doing my stuff, end the external process by launching another "stop my server" command.
5. When both commands complete, end the task.

This is like starting a server to run integration tests, but this is not a tomcat/jetty type server, so it needs to be launch from command line and wait for server to be "ready" via the server's stdout.

I am currently able to use the exec task to run my task and get the output. So I think I can probably code in Groovy/Java to achieve what I want.

However, it seems tedious to code this seemingly common pattern. So I am wondering if there's an easier way to solve such problems without too much coding - i.e. is this a common pattern that gradle has a DSL for?

Note that I am a newbie at Gradle, so any advise around this topic would also be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there's no out-of-the-box support for it. I implemented a [task](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/gae/task/GaeRunTask.groovy) that does something similar. That code might give you a start.

Comment: @kctang if you be specific on the technologies you use we can provide you precise solution. Not that you really need to through gradle coding but also some integrator testing framework which runs embeded testing framework.

Comment: @Rajmahendra It is a custom development Java RMI server/client. I need the server app write stdout "===Server Ready===" before I can connect using the Java RMI client to confirm server is working properly, then shutdown and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, current version of Gradle (1.4) has no dedicated DSL support for starting up/shutting down external processes. You can implement it in groovy right inside build script, it should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The overall pattern: probably not - too many different possibilities/combinations for there to be any kind of standard template.

But it's simple to build your own logic with a set of tasks.
The most complicated part is the waiting for the external process, which Gradle does have a DSL for (Ant actually has the core logic/DSL, Gradle is just wrapping it).

This is my task to wait for Postgres to come up inside a local docker container:

```
task waitForLocalDb(){
  group = 'docker.db'
  mustRunAfter localApiSvcDbRunCleanContainer
  doFirst{
    println "waiting for Postgres to come up"
    ant.waitfor(
      maxwait:"10", maxwaitunit:"second", 
      checkevery:"500", checkeveryunit: "millisecond"
    ){
      socket(server:"192.168.99.100", port:"5544")
    }
  }
}
```

This waits for Postgres by checking for it to be listening on the specified port.

You can use the Ant [waitfor](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html) task to do various things  - like check for the server to say "server is ready" in a file somewhere ("in stdout" would very much depend on how you were launching your process).

Or you could check for "server is ready" or something like that in a specific URL, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548226/924597

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver. I have a project where I need to start a container with a DB, wait for the DB to be accessible, then use a JOOQ task to generate some sources, then stop the container. That wait task... I lost a day trying to make it happen, and then this morning, I stumbled upon this entry. This is the only way that did it for me. Thank you kind sir!